# is it possible to round the 4 edges of a border

Tags: css

So when I say border - i mean as in `border-bottom: 10px solid red` - so I can make this no longer a rectangle, but a rounded rectangle?

```css
.item {
border-bottom: 10px solid red;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
float: left;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">This is a div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a border on the element itself. You can't make *just* the bottom border into a rounded rectangle, using things like `border-radius` will only round the *bottom* corners of the *bottom* border.

Instead, use the `::after` pseudo element:

```css
.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.item::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">This is a div</div>
```

Comment: Yeh - I've done this in most areas - but wanted to add a border to a table - so favoured using the actual border property. Is it not possible using the border property?